# Verificar se o email preenchido já existe no banco de dados PHP

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Não to conseguindo cadastrar nem verificar os emails,se alguém[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] poder ajudar....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Na sua primeira query tente...

$verifica = mysqli_query("SELECT * FROM cadastro where email = '$emailc');

email: substitua pelo nome que esta no seu banco.

$emailc: creio que seja o email passado para cadastro....

removi o Limite 1 pois essa query busca no banco o cadastro com este email caso ele encontre, sim ira buscar mais de um se você não coloco o email como único la no banco e tiver mais de um cadastro com mesmo email, como você quer que seja único mude isso no banco para nao aceita o cadastro de email igual.

De qualquer forma mudar no banco o email para unico ja resolve seu prublema talvez tirando ate a necessidade de verificar se ele possui no banco antes de incluir outro cadastro, pois ele como unico quando tentar inserir um cadastro te retornaria um erro.

Comment: ta registrando os emails,só que ta registrando emails repetidos,nao quero que repita...=/

Comment: como eu disse e só ir no banco e mudar sua coluna de email para único, com isso ele não aceitara inserir emails repetidos.

Comment: deu certo,o prolema era da versão do WAMP,vlw mano